# Populate form inputs from dropdown options, parsing json data attributes

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, forms

A select dropdown menu is populated after a MySQL query, yielding something like

```
<form method="post" action="action.php">
   <select name="elements" id="elements">
      <option type="text" value="">Select an element to be modified, or fill data below for a new one</option>
      <option type="text" value="1" data-json='{"elements_id":"1","elements_field1":"Lorem ipsum","elements_field2":"Foo"}'>Element 1</option>
      <option type="text" value="2" data-json='{"elements_id":"2","elements_field1":"Lorem ipsum again","elements_field2":"Foo again"}'>Element 2</option>
   </select>
   <input type="text" id="elements_id">
   <input type="text" id="elements_field1">
   <input type="text" id="elements_field2">
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I would like that the various input fields be populated dynamically according to the selection in the droplist above.

Following suggestions found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31620499/dynamically-fill-multiple-input-fields-from-mysql-depending-on-the-drop-list-ite), I've tried including the following script in the `<head>` section of my php file:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
   $('#elements').on('change', function() {
       var selected = $(this).find('option[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').data('json');
       $('#elements_id').val(selected.elements_id);
       $('#elements_field1').val(selected.elements_field1);
       $('#elements_field2').val(selected.elements_field2);
   });
</script>
```

But this does not work, and does not even result in an error which I can track through the browser's Web Console. I presume it has to do with the json formatting coming as an output of a MySQL query (not shown, but validated as a regular json), or with the json parsing by the script.

Any hint or suggestion? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to work for me. The only mistake is that you are setting the value of the second input twice. Fixing that, [here's a JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/vevifep/2/edit?html,js,output).

```
$('#elements').on('change', function() {
  var selected = $(this).find('option[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').data('json');
  console.log( selected );
  $('#elements_id').val(selected.elements_id);
  $('#elements_field1').val(selected.elements_field1);
  $('#elements_field2').val(selected.elements_field2); // <-- Here was your error
});
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out: that was a slip, produced in the attempt of simplifying my original code (slightly more complex). However, even correcting that, and copying-and-pasting my own example in a separate php file, it does not work :( Could that depend on some configuration option?

Comment: I've moved the javascript to right before the `</body>` as explained here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13702123/my-javascript-code-is-not-working-locally-but-works-fine-on-jsfiddle-why) and it now works properly, many thanks!